# Dynamiclly creating a certain amount of arraylists based on method input. (JAVA)

Tags: java, arraylist, dynamic

I have code that takes a wav file and generates various double values based on it's structure.

I also have a threshold value depending on these values.

Anything above this threshold is a significant value.

I want to sort all groups of consectucitve values above the threshold into a double ArrayList (These will be significant events).

I want to put these double ArrayLists into an Arraylist where each element is a double ArrayList. (An ArrayList of ArrayLists):

This is my coded attempt so far:

```
ArrayList<Double> significantEvent = new ArrayList<Double>();

ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> significantEventCollect = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();

for (int loop = 0; loop <  values.size(); loop++) {


    if (values.get(loop) >= threshold) {
        significantEvent.add(values.get(loop));
         System.out.println(values.get(loop));

    } else if (values.get(loop) < threshold && significantEvent.size() > 0) {
         System.out.println("");


        significantEventCollect.add(significantEvent);


        significantEvent.clear();



    }
}

//Each element appears to be empty at this point

for (int loop = 0 ; loop < significantEventCollect.size(); loop ++) {
    System.out.println(" Element size " + significantEventCollect.get(loop).size());

    }
```

Instead of having the same ArrayList of values being added to the ArrayList collection before being cleared and refilled,

I would like to have a new arrayList everytime a new group of values exceeds the threshold and add this to the ArrayList collection.

I am not sure how to get the code to dynamically keep creating new unique Arraylist objects (the amount of which will depend on the wav file being inputed in the method)

Any advice about how to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't call clear(). You don't want to clear the inner list that you just added to the outer list. You want to leave it as is, and create a **new** arraylist: `significantEvent = new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: Lists are passed by reference, so you're adding to `significantEventCollect` the same list over and over (and clearing it after each insertion). Create a new ArrayList instead of reusing the same.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you it worked, I didn't relize you could do that without creating unique new names for the object each time. Greatly appreciated !

Comment: Objects don't have names. `significantEventCollect`is the name of a **variable**. The value of a variable, by definition of "variable", can vary.